# Combined query in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two tables

1. userfriendrequests
2. userfriends

I want to get all on my userfriendrequests data but exclude those userfriendrequests.UserID which are existing in my userfriends.FriendID list

My ID is 1, and I want to retrieve my friend request.

userfriendrequests-table
the list of my friend request

```
UserID          FriendID
    2               1
    3               1
    4               1
    5               1
    6               1
    7               1
```

userfriends-table
the list of my friends

```
UserID          FriendID
    1               22
    1               23
    1               33
    1               55
    1               2
    1               3
```

The result should be:

```
userfriendrequests
UserID          FriendID
    4               1
    5               1
    6               1
    7               1
```

Now how can I do this in linq in a single query only?

This is what I have tried so far:
USING DOUBLE QUERY

```
List<FriendRequest> myFriendRequest = new List<FriendRequest>();
using (dbasecoreEntities dbase = Logic.Utility.dbaseContext())
{
    var ufr = (from uf in dbase.userfriendrequests
               where uf.FriendID == details.UserID && !uf.IsBlocked && !uf.IsIgnored && uf.UserID != details.UserID
               select uf).OrderBy(i => i.RequestDate).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

    var myfriends = (from frnd in dbase.userfriends where frnd.UserID == details.UserID select frnd.FriendID).ToList();
    ufr = ufr.Where(i => !myfriends.Any(j => j == i.UserID)).ToList();

    myFriendRequest = (from userFriend in ufr
                   select new FriendRequest(userFriend, details.GMTTimeZone)).ToList();
}

return myFriendRequest;
```

USING SINGLE QUERY. But this one takes a very very long time to return results.

```
using (dbasecoreEntities dbase = Logic.Utility.dbaseContext())
{
    var list = (from uf in dbase.userfriendrequests.Where(i => i.FriendID == details.UserID && !i.IsBlocked && !i.IsIgnored && i.UserID != details.UserID).AsEnumerable()
                where !dbase.userfriends.Where(i => i.UserID == details.UserID).Any(j => j.UserID == uf.UserID)
                select new FriendRequest(uf)).OrderBy(i => i.RequestDate).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

    return list;
}
```

In here I'm using AsEnumerable so I can directly use select new FriendRequest(uf)

The DOUBLE QUERY takes less than 7 seconds for 10 records, and more than a minute for 100 records.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to Entities?

Comment: Yes. I'm using entity framework, and VS2012

Comment: Why don't you want to mark Accepted/Declined requests? Or delete them after any user action?

Comment: @Uriil I honestly don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do group join. If friend(s) was not found for current user, then select user

```
var query = from uf in dbase.userfriendrequests
            join frnd in dbase.userfriends 
                 on uf.UserID equals frnd.FriendID into g
            where !g.Any()
            select uf;
```

Instead of `!g.Any()` you can use `g.Count() == 0`.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to work as entity framework maps .Any to nested unions so is still going to have a huge performance hit....

Comment: @user1793607 can't now verify performance, but I don't see other options to do task in one query.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Thanks. It works fine. Anyway `g.Count() == 0` is more faster than `g.Any()`

Answer (score 1):

Think it will have the same performance hit but can give

```
var query = dbase.userfriendsrequests.Select(user => new 
                                             { 
                                              UserID = user.FriendID,
                                              FriendID = user.UserID
                                             }
                 .Except(
                   dbase.userfriends.Select(frnd => new 
                                             { 
                                              UserID = frnd.FriendID,
                                              FriendID = frnd.UserID
                                             });
```

a go